# @Value can not autowired from properities

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, properties

The bean definition is as below:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.ma2oo.model.domain.User;
import com.ma2oo.model.res.interfaces.IUserService;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:exam-binary.properties")
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {
    private static final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Value("${user.post.uri}")
    private String registerUri;

    public User register(final User user) {
        System.out.println(registerUri.toString());
        return restTemplate.postForObject(registerUri, user, User.class);
    }

    @Bean(name = "userServiceImpl")
    public IUserService getUserService() {
        return new UserServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

The imported properties file is under `src/main/resources`.
And the variable is like:

```
user.post.uri=http://localhost:9000/users/newUser
```

Method used to call this function is like:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(UserServiceImpl.class);
IUserService userService = (UserServiceImpl) applicationContext.getBean("userServiceImpl");
User result = userService.register(register);
```

The standard output for the function `register()` is `${user.post.uri}`, that means the value doesn't be autowired.
Exception description is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'user.post.uri'
```

Could anyone help with this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add been `propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in your configuration,

```
   @Bean
   public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
      return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   }
```

@PropertySource annotation does not automatically register a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with Spring. Instead, the bean must be explicitly defined in the configuration to get the property resolution mechanism working.[[reference]](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/#java)

Read more about it in [spring docs.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)